# Performance hit while using useMemo to prevent re-rendering of array of child components | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If we use useMemo to memoize child components say an array of individual book to prevent re-rendering. Wouldn't it effect the performance of the app by consuming more memory to save the states?

Child-

```js
const Book = ({ item }) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    console.log(item.name);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{item.name}</p>
        <p>{item.author.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }, [item]);
};
```

Parent-

```js
const Books = (props) => {
  const books = props.data.books.map((item) => {
    return <Book key={item.id} item={item} />;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("render button");
            props.func();
          }}
        >
          Add new
        </button>
        <div>{books}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

If the props.data.books array is huge in size then, Wouldn't it effect the performance of the app by consuming more memory to save the states?
What is the industry practice? Does facebook use useMemo for a post/story?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please revise your post to a *single* unambiguously answerable question.

Comment: @possum My question is about using useMemo for an large array of child components, would it affect performance?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React hook `useMemo` should be used for preventing **expensive** re-renders. Your `Book` component is **very cheap** to render, as it basically do nothing but show some data, which already are stored in memory. And `Book` component is provided with `key` attribute, so there is no problem for React to render many of them, unless you need to show at least thousands of them at once.

Expensive render could mean counting derived data - statistics, graphs etc. If such operations are needed, you may consider using data store instead (like Redux + Relect)

There is no sharp line when `useMemo` should be used. As you expected, it can do more hurt than good.

https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useMemo